# Convert string to time struct in Golang

Tags: go, time, type-conversion

My method registers the current time in this format

```
now = time.Now().format(time.RFC3339)
```

And I want to assign it to

```
message.LastReadAt = &now // field LastReadAt *time.Time`example:"2020-05-01T15:00:00Z"` of Message type
```

But I get this message when I try to "message.LastReadAt = &now"

```
Cannot use '&now' (type *string) as type *time.Time
```

How do I convert the variable "now" back to the "*time.Time" type?

Comment: you can possibly use `time.Parse`, https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse

Comment: `now = time.Now().format(time.RFC3339)` cannot  be your code, it would not  compile. But calling  `Format` on a time.Time produces a `string` which is not a `time.Time` and not  a `*time.Time`. Please take the Tour of Go to understand that Go's variables are typed and how they work.

Comment: I already know what the problem, I am looking for a solution here. I need a variable of type time.Time in the RFC3339 format.

Comment: A variable of type `time.Time` isn't in any format; formats are only relevant when converting between a `string` and a `time.Time`. If you need the current time as a `time.Time`, just use `now := time.Now()`.

Comment: "I need a variable of type time.Time in the RFC3339 format." A variable of time.Time _cannot_ be in the RFC3339 format because RFC3339 defines a string.

Comment: I think I got now, thanks Adrian!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Sheshnath. It looks like you need to use `time.Parse` https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse.

Since you already specified a format, `time.RFC3339`, in your use of `time.Now()`, you should be able to do

```
t, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, now)
message.LastReadAt = t
```